# Return type of list front (C++)

Tags: c++, function, reference, linked-list, return-type

So I want to use a list for a part of my program. I'm trying to get acquainted to the library *list*, so I wrote a quick little program to help myself understand what's going on. It all works properly, but there's one thing I don't understand.

According to this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/front/
The return type for the front function should be a *reference* of the type (in this case, room) of the first element (the only element in this case).

But I was able to access the values without having to reference, because it seems that all the values were passed directly (not by reference). Is this expected? Is the website wrong? Is my compiler wrong (CodeBlocks 13.12)?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct room {
    int content;
    struct room * north;
    struct room * south;
    struct room * east;
    struct room * west;
} ;

int main ()
{
    list<room> mylist;
    cout << ( mylist.empty() ? "List is empty.\n" : "List is not empty.\n" ) << endl;

    room * room1 = new room;
    room1->content = 15;
    cout
    << room1->content << "\n"
    << room1->north << "\n"
    << room1->south << "\n"
    << room1->east << "\n"
    << room1->west << "\n";

    cout << "\n" << room1 << endl;

    mylist.push_front(*room1);
    cout << ( mylist.empty() ? "\nList is empty.\n" : "\nList is not empty.\n" ) << endl;

    delete room1;

    room test_room = mylist.front();

    cout
    << test_room.content << "\n"
    << test_room.north << "\n"
    << test_room.south << "\n"
    << test_room.east << "\n"
    << test_room.west << "\n";

    cout << "\n" << &test_room << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, you're just copying the front `room`. Is that your question?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But according to the website, shouldn't I be getting a pointer (of type room) as the return value from the function _front_? Or am I misunderstanding the definition of the word reference?

Comment: @MaxJacob, a reference != pointer, read up on it [here](/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference) and also [here](/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That should help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of constructors added automatically to any class you declare: The default constructor, which default-initializes all members of that class `§12.1.4` and the **copy constructor** `§12.8.7`.

In your case, we have to take a look at the *copy constructor*:

The declaration of the copy constructor looks like this (if you would write it down specifically `§12.8.8`):

```
struct room{
    room(const room&); // Copy-Ctor, implicitly added by the compiler
};
```

As you can see, it takes a `const` reference to another `room` and initilizes all values of itself by copying from the passed in `room`.

---

The first thing that happens is that the list adds a copy of the `room` you passed into `mylist.push_front(*room1)` (you can see that `push_front()` takes elements by const-ref `§23.3.5.4` but internally copies them. To do this, the copy-constructor is called the first time.

When you later access the element with `mylist.front()` it returns a reference but because you initialize a value of `room`, instead of a reference - `room test_room = mylist.front();` - the copy-constructor is invoked a second time. *To correctly capture the front of the list by reference you need to do* `room& test_room = mylist.front();`.

Note: All `§nbr` refer to the according section in the C++ standard.

Comment: Why would it not be this?:
`room * test_room = mylist.front()`

Comment: See the link I posted above or [again the same link here](/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in). Welcome to stackexchange btw

Comment: Thank you both for helping me out!

Comment: The default constructor default-initializes its members, it doesn't zero-initialize them. `push_front()` takes its argument by reference to const, not by value.

Comment: Thanks @Barry, looked it up in t the standard, fixed and added paragraphs